# gnome-open confused: Could not display "/home/msw/anything"

Tags: gnome, 11.04, mime-type

My trusted friend `gnome-open` (which I call `go` for short) has ceased working. It interprets any argument given to it as a directory and will not recognize anything else.

I have traced out the somewhat indirect path connecting the [gnome menu system](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/menustructure-1.html.en) which in turn relies upon the [XDG subsystem](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/menu-spec?action=show&redirect=Standards/menu-spec) which requires `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`, `/usr/share/application/mimeinfo.cache` which itself is generated by update-mime-database(1) which requires that `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` be set properly.

Everything seems in order and yet mime-type recognition is not working. This would be tolerable from the shell (because I usually know the mime-type of the file I want to open), but applications like Chrome cannot launch anything properly.

I'm sure I've missed something, and this is on a machine under daily desktop use that was recently updated to Natty Beta 1 (and is current to the repos as of one hour ago). I don't know that the gnome-open failure was caused by the upgrade or followed it during some package installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. I've searched launchpad and found a similar report for unity dash

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-files/+bug/751374

Comment: Yeppers, that was it. Fortunately, my aged boot disk started reporting imminent failure shortly after posting the question. So a new drive and new installation cleared the problem. Not that I'm suggesting that is the workaround...